# Sort the users in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

This is my code below, please tell me how to sort users in MongoDb alphabetically!

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
 
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    }, 

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    avatar: {
        type: String
    },

    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

}, {
    collection: 'users'
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

Comment: Maybe `db.User.sort( { name: 1 } )` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create indexes that support the efficient execution of queries in MongoDB, reduce query time.
You can try:

```
UserSchema.index({ name: 1 })
```

With this code, MongoDB will create an `name` index and MongoDB will sort it by ascending order.
[Read more about indexes in Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes)
And [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)